# Event : Workflow Email Alert Template - Add to Calendar Button(s)?

Tags: email-template, email-alert, calendar, workflowrule

> **Issue:** We have a request from our Education department to send our customers an email reminder when we book a new Event with them. We
>   have a large no-show problem with customers forgetting about their
>   booked events with us and are hoping to solve some of it by sending
>   them an email reminder as soon as the event is booked. Inside of this email we would like to embed functionality to automatically add the Event to
>   their calendar via a simple "Add to Calendar" link. Ideally we'd like to support all Calendars, but at a bare minimum we want to support **Outlook, iCalendar, and Google Calendar**.

From my research, I've determined that Google Calendar seems easiest - Google supports URL parameters that allow me to just pass in Event specific details using merge fields into the URL which brings up a new window for that event to be saved to the Google Calendar.

> **Problem:** Outlook and iCalendar however are not as simple as Google, apparently. It looks like they both support the .ics file
>   format (the universal Calendar Event file type), but neither of them
>   have a URL available that I can pass parameters to. From the research
>   I've done ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831877/how-do-i-create-a-link-to-add-an-entry-to-a-calendar)) and ([Here](http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2008/04/14/generate-outlook-calendar-events-with-php-and-icalendar/)) it appears that the only
>   approach to handling the creation of these .ics files is to have a PHP
>   page that serves an .ics file via the text/Calendar mimetype and a
>   bunch of different data points for the Event - resulting in the php
>   page serving a downloadable .ics to then be opened in another
>   application.

Salesforce doesn't support the hosting of PHP files, so this option is not viable if I want to keep everything within the Salesforce platform. I've also tried a website called "AddThisEvent" (suggested in the answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831877/how-do-i-create-a-link-to-add-an-entry-to-a-calendar)) but it requires that we embed a javascript reference in the `<head>` of the page which doesn't work with email clients.

> **Question:** So ultimately my question is - can this be done within Email Alerts/Visualforce Pages/Apex without the need for an external
>   PHP page? Or will I need to have our marketing/web team create a PHP
>   page that is capable of receiving parameters, interpreting them, and
>   outputting a correct .ics? I'm looking to solve this problem without
>   apps, but welcome any and all suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with a simple VisualForce page by changing the ContentType attribute of the `<apex:page>` and by setting the Content-Disposition via a custom controller with `ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().put('content-disposition','inline; filename=calendarEvent.ics');` in the constructor

```
<apex:page ContentType="text/Calendar" controller="CalendarInviteController">
    BEGIN:VCALENDAR
    VERSION:2.0
    PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    UID:uid1@example.com
    DTSTAMP:20170426T203000
    ORGANIZER;CN=ABC CO:MAILTO:education@ABCCo.com
    DTSTART:{!startDate}
    DTEND:{!endDate}
    SUMMARY:{!summary}
    STATUS:CONFIRMED
    LOCATION: {!location}
    END:VEVENT
    END:VCALENDAR
</apex:page>
```

---

```
public class CalendarInviteController {

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }


    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }


    public String getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }
    public String getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    private final String startDate;
    private final String endDate;
    private final String summary;
    private final String location;

    public CalendarInviteController(){
        ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().put('content-disposition','inline; filename=calendarEvent.ics');

        startDate = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('startDate');
        endDate = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('endDate');
        summary = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('summary');
        location = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('location');
    }
}
```